# How to upgrade apache 2.2.15 to apache 2.4.12 on CentOS 6.6?

Tags: apache, centos

I tried ,but didn't work for me.

Apache 2.4 on CentOS 6.6:

Step 1:

```
cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
wget http://repos.fedorapeople.org/repos/jkaluza/httpd24/epel-httpd24.repo
```

Step 2:

```
yum install httpd24.x86_64
```

Step 3:

```
$ /opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd -version
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (Red Hat)
Server built:   Sep 25 2013 05:25:46
NOTE: config files are in: /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd

$ ls
conf  conf.d  conf.modules.d  logs  modules  run
EDIT: in case you want to switch off Apache 2.2

$ chkconfig httpd off
$ chkconfig --list | grep httpd
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
httpd24-httpd   0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
EDIT 2: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/PHP-FPM

yum install php-fpm
/etc/init.d/php-fpm start
```

Does any body knows the solutions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best if you built it yourself from the Apache source code on a CentOS 6.6 system.

Compiling and Installing Apache 2.4:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/install.html

Make note of the configure line during the build so you can make sure it includes all the modules you want (Like mod_ssl...etc..).  Details on what is available for the `configure` line located here http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/configure.html

```
$ CC="pgcc" CFLAGS="-O2" \
./configure --prefix=/sw/pkg/apache \
--enable-ldap=shared \
--enable-lua=shared
```

If you want your own RPM, create a SPEC file with your own customizations.